# Directly similar triangle proof

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> Suppose the triangles $ABC$ and $AB'C'$ are directly similar. Then assuming $BB'$ and $CC'$ intersect, determine under which extra conditions $A,B,C$ and $BB'\cap CC'$ lie on a circle.

[image: DirectlySimilarTriangle]

I think the two triangles being directly similar and $BB'$ and $CC'$ intersecting is insufficient to conclude that $A,B,C$ and $BB'\cap CC'$ lie on a circle. I think it's possible the circumcircles of triangles $ABC$ and $AB'C'$ intersect at only the point $A$. Now assume the circumcircles of triangles $ABC$ and $AB'C'$ intersect at a point $P$ other than $A$. Then $\angle APB =\angle ACB = \angle AC'B'=\angle APB'$ by the inscribed angle theorem and similarity. But does this imply that $P$ lies on the line $BB'$ and similarly on the line $CC'$? If so, why? Also, is it sufficient and necessary to add the condition that the circumcircles intersect in more than one point?

Comment: It can be proven easily that $A$, $B$, $C$, and $BB'CC'$ lie on a circle using angle chasing  only without imposing any additional condition. You don't even need to bring the circumcircle of $\triangle AB'C'$ into the picture to do this.  If you are interested in this proof, I can post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $AB$ be transformed into $AB'$ by a rotation and scale factor. Then $AC$ is transformed into $AC'$ by the same rotation and scale factor.

Therefore $ABB'$ and $ACC'$ are similar.

Then angles $ABD$ and $ACD$ sum to $\pi$. Therefore $ABCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral as required.